# How do i add an Element with xsl to an XML File?

Tags: xml, xslt

I extracted numbers from an XML File and like to add them to a new element.
I tried to add the Element first and after that the new Informations.

XML-File:

```
<products>
 <product>
    <OrderingInfo>
        <item name="Part No.">12345 (text)</item>
        <item name="Part No.">12345IP (text)</item>
    </OrderingInfo>
 </product>

 <product>
    <OrderingInfo>
        <item name="Part No.">001 (text)</item>
        <item name="Part No.">002 (text)</item>
    </OrderingInfo>
 </product>
```

Desired output:

```
<products>
 <product>
    <OrderingInfo>
        <item name="Part No.">12345 (text)</item>
        <item name="Part No.">12345IP (text)</item>
    </OrderingInfo>
    <varitems>
    </varitems>
</product>

 <product>
    <OrderingInfo>
        <item name="Part No.">001</item>
        <item name="Part No.">002</item>
    </OrderingInfo>
    <varitems>
    </varitems>
 </product>
```

But I don't know how it is possible to add an Element and then use it? 
This is the code I tried it with

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OrderingInfo">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <varitems></varitems>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="varitems">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::product/OrderingInformation/item">
                <item>
                    <partno><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(../item[1], ' ')"/></partno>
                    <varno><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before(current(),' '))"/></varno>
                    <vartitle><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(substring-after(current(),' '),'()',''))"/></vartitle>
                </item>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The main part I am looking for is the first on (adding varitems) and use it afterwards. (the rest is fine)

Answer (score 0):

As `varitems` element is child of `product` in the desired output, you can simply generate it directly by making `product` template.

```
<xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <varitems>
        </varitems>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: i edit my XML desired output. I don't want `<item></item>` only add varitems. Is it the same code?

Comment: I modified the answer according to your requirement change.

Comment: You cant make template that match `varitems` elements that is generated in the template because it is only serialized into the output.  So your template `xsl:template/@match="varitems"` has no effect in the output. Are you really understand this mechanism?